# HTML Content div spacing

Tags: html, margins

I'm studying code that I found on the net and faced problem. When I add text to the main div called content, I get no margins, text is too close to sidebar. How should I fix it? Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="inner">
            <div id="sidebar"></div>  
            <div id="content">
        </div>  
    </div>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#outer {width:1000px;margin:0 auto;}
#inner {overflow:hidden;}
#header {min-height:40px;background:#bbb}
#content {width:900;min-height:900px;float:left;background:#ccc;clear:}
#sidebar{width:100px;min-height:250px;float:left;background:#ddd}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing one closing tag there?

Comment: Might be, but I think there's problem in CSS code. Have any ideas?

Comment: It also might help us answer your question if you add a link to where you found it.

Comment: first things first - close the tag!

Answer (score 0):

Use padding and/or margins on your content and/or sidebar div in the CSS

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/margins/

Comment: I try, but then my whole page mess up. What would you add to code, to make text 50px from the left?

Comment: Try making the width of the content 850px and putting a left margin of 50px on it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something such as

```
#content{box-sizing:border-box, width:900;min-height:900px;float:left;background:#ccc; padding:10px;}
```

Using "box-sizing" should ensure it doesn't mess up your page.

edit: and yeah, close that html, that could really help.

Comment: box sizing is great but it will fail in older browsers and break the whole layout.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you need exactly. But try to add  `padding-left` or `margin-left`

```
#content {width:900;min-height:900px;float:left;background:#ccc;padding-left:20px;margin-left:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the content div add another div and use margins on it.

You can also use a paragraph tag and same use margins on it, this will not break your layout.

Also you are missing a closing tag, this definatly needs to be fixed.

Try:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="inner">
            <div id="sidebar"></div>  
            <div id="content">
               <div class="box">
                all text and content comes here
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</html>
```

Additional CSS:

```
.box {
margin:50px;
}
```

Comment: I tried everything you told, but my page is still broken or text too close. I think I will just find another sample of similar layout... Thanks your help

Comment: its not broke you probably just made a mistake see http://jsbin.com/egiwev/1/edit